# How to use query.explain() of mongodb from mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, mongoengine

I am trying analyze my query performances and would like improve them. I use mongoengine wrapper. I am not able find way to use explain() from mongoengine although I am using query logs and getting the raw mongo queries and running explain I would like to use explain via mongoengine  to make my monitoring less cumbersome. Any ideas

Comment: [?](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.explain)

Answer (score 6):

You can use explain eg:

```
MyDoc.objects(x=y).explain()
```

See: [QuerySet.explain()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.explain)